# About some properties of the Mathieu Group ${ M }_{ 9 }$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The Mathieu Group ${ M }_{ 9 }$ of order 72 is given by ${ M }_{ 9 }=\left< (1,4,9,8)(2,5,3,6),(1,6,5,2)(3,7,9,8) \right> $
I'd like to show two things (I read them while reading a little introduction to the Mathieu Groups).
First: How can one show that ${ C }_{ 3 }\times { C }_{ 3 }\lhd { M }_{ 9 }$?
I tried using Sylow (3) but here we encounter the problem that the two sylow 3 subgroups are not unique hence no normal subgroups ( if I'm not mistaken).

Second Question: How can one show that: ${ M }_{ 9 }/{ (C }_{ 3 }\times { { C }_{ 3 }) }\cong { Q }_{ 8 }$
haven't had any ideas for this one yet.

Comment: You are mistaken - there is a unique Sylow $3$-subgroup.

Comment: but aren't there two of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $C_3\times C_3$ is a $3$-Sylow subgroup in $M_9$. Since $s_3=1$, it is normal. We have $M_9\cong (C_3\times C_3)\rtimes Q_8$. The action here is via the faithful irreducible representation of quaternion group (a two-dimensional irreducible representation) over the field $\Bbb{F}_3$. This representation can be thought of as the embedding of $Q_8$ in $GL(2,3)$.

Comment: How can i argue that this sylow-3-subgroup is unique dont we have 72=2*2*2*3*3

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ypur argument does not appear to rule out $n_3=4$. Another way to see it is that the stabilizers are disjoint, so we have $9 \times 7 = 63$ elements of order $2$ or $4$, leaving only $9$ other elements, which must make up the unique Sylow $3$-subgroup.